# The creation of bundle by webpack might be a problem to download

Tags: webpack

I was learning how Webpack works. As I found out one of the webpack's benefits is that out of several files webpack creates one bundle. I know the benefit of the creation of bundle is that instead of making several HTTP requests and with bundle we make only one request which does not stress the web server. The question is How can a bundle be useful since the bundle can weigh much in terms of size and which can take long time to download? That is, one combined file can be, say, big in size and it will take longer to download rather than to download several small files. I am just confused about this

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, even if initially our JS bundle have big size, there is something called "tree shaking" which removes all of the unnecessary code from the bundle. So, the bundle will ultimately contain only the code we need. For more info https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-webpack-module-bundling/